# How do I preserve my first character after doing a regular expression split?

Tags: ruby, regex, string, split

I'm using Rails 5.  I'm trying to split on a regular expression but it seems to be cutting off the first character of the item after the split.  I have

```
2.4.0 :044 >   tokens = ["12.BILL R. PRESTON"]
 => ["12.BILL R. PRESTON"] 
2.4.0 :045 > tokens = tokens.flat_map { |token| token =~ /\d\.[a-z]/i ? token.split(/\d\.[a-z]/i) : token } 
 => ["1", "ILL R. PRESTON"]
```

I would expect the outcome to be

```
["1", "BILL R. PRESTON"]
```

but the "B" is getting removed.  How can I adjust my split expression?

Comment: And you want `"1"`, not `"12"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?=[a-z])` so that the `B` is not consumed in the split:

```
tokens.flat_map { |token| token =~ /\d\.[a-z]/i ? token.split(/\d\.(?=[a-z])/i) : token }
=> ["1", "BILL R. PRESTON"]
```

And if you want to keep both the `2` and the `B`, you can add a lookbehind `(?<=\d)`:

```
tokens.flat_map { |token| token =~ /\d\.[a-z]/i ? token.split(/(?<=\d)\.(?=[a-z])/i) : token }
=> ["12", "BILL R. PRESTON"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
tokens = ["12.BILL R. PRESTON", "238.BETTY Z. BOOP"]

tokens.map { |s| s.split(/(?<=\d)\d+\./) }
  #=> [["1", "BILL R. PRESTON"], ["2", "BETTY Z. BOOP"]] 

If you want all the digits split off, remove `\d+`:

tokens.map { |s| s.split(/(?<=\d)\./) }
  #=> [["12", "BILL R. PRESTON"], ["238", "BETTY Z. BOOP"]]
```

Comment: I had already accepted the answer, not realizing that my number was also getting cut off, so your alternate solution really helped me out.